# ImageView is getting stretched out in landscape mode

Tags: android, imageview, aspect-ratio

I would like to maintain the aspect ratio of my Imageview even in landscape mode.It looks super stretched even if I use scaleType :fitXY and adjustBounds Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/image" />
        />
   </FrameLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Update:
I get set my imageview using glide . Its mostly a 640 X 330 image

```
       Glide.with(this)
            .load("http://www.web-cars.com/lambo_sb/IMG_3410.jpg")
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: set  imageview width wrap_content.  android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: `FitXY` will always strech because ultimately X in Landscape will always be greater than X in portrait mode.

Comment: `FitXY` is supposed to stretch the image to fill the screen.Try overriding `onConfigurationChanged`

Comment: FitXY scales X and Y independently, so it might change the aspect ratio. Use FitCenter

Comment: remove scale type and show normal image then check it is stretched or not in landscape mode

Comment: Please check answer you can get some help from glide library

Comment: I tried fitCenter .It gets aligned to the center but then I the imageview is not stretched along the width

Answer (score 0):

Use PercentFrameLayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html

Create two layout files for portrait and landscape configurations

Portrait

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <ImageView
      app:layout_aspectRatio="136%"
      app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
      tools:src="@color/accent"
      />

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Landscape

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <ImageView
      app:layout_aspectRatio="136%"
      app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
      tools:src="@color/accent"
      />

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Comment: how widthPercent 100 will help him

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="24dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
            />
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related but can help if you do not want landscape mode at all set in AndroidManifest.xml file to activity  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` so as you do not enter the landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

I think this will resolve your problem when you are not sure about size of image from server.

```
Glide.with(this)
                .load("http://www.web-cars.com/lambo_sb/IMG_3410.jpg")
                .centerCrop()
                .override(200, 200)
                .into(imgView);
```

-Image Resizing and Cropping
you are not sure about the size of the image loaded from the remote server

```
that what will be the size of the image . so in this code snippet image is resized to 200X200 and center cropped.


Glide.with(this)
        .load("IMAGE URL HERE")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)
        .override(200, 200);
        .centerCrop();
        .into(imageView);
```

Enjoy Coding and Share Knowledge

Link :

```
[http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/glide-image-loading-library-for-android-tutorial/][1]
```